# why is this google bigquery getService() method wrong?

Tags: java, google-bigquery

[image]

I hava imported the `com.google.cloud.bigquery.*` package.

Why is this Google Bigquery `getService()` method wrong?

Comment: Please post code snippets instead of images. Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think it is wrong? what error do you get when you compile?